# Android Programming - Sending Data

Tags: java, android, database, storage

Good day

I am on the lookout for a way to send data from an Android app to a localized site. Let's say for instance I want the User to enter in Text, this text needs to be searched through a database and when there is a hit the User gets the relevant information regarding the User's input.

And when the text the User entered is not on the database the information the User input gets added.

What can I use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should go through any sqlite tutorial. You can understand the flow for insertion of data and also you can get data using search.[enter link description here](https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/how-to-fetch-data-from-sqlite-database-in-android/)

All the best.